# What are the implication of iommu=soft?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, amd, iommu

I've got new laptop at work (Lenovo A485) and there are few issues with it. It prints `AMD-Vi: IOAPIC[32] not in IVRS table` and kernel panic after that. So far I've figured few ways to get the system up and running.

- `noapic` - terrible performance and high temperature, so not really a good way to do it
- `amd_iommu=off` - not ideal either
- `ivrs_ioapic[32]=00:14.0 ivrs_ioapic[33]=00:00.2` - this seems to work fine
- `iommu=soft`

My questions are about `iommu=soft`. I'm not sure what exactly it does. What are the implications of this mode? What is preferable, overriding the IVRS table or iommu=soft?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`iommu=soft` tells the kernel to use a software implementation to remap memory for applications that can't read above the 4GB limit.

The kernel documentation for these options is here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/x86_64/boot-options.txt

What's preferable is a solution that satisfies your expectations for performance, system temperature, battery life, etc, etc.  If `iommu=soft` give you satisfactory performance, temperature, and battery life, then I would say go with that.